# libpq library in centos

Tags: postgresql, centos7

I'm using Centos 7 and I have a challenge find a postgresql library called libpq. I have it installed but when I run 'pkg­-config libpq --cflags --libs' I get 'No package 'libpq' found'.

when I run 'rpm -qa | grep libpq' I get this here:
libpqxx-devel-5.0.1-2.rhel7.x86_64
libpqxx-5.0.1-2.rhel7.x86_64.

What could be the issue here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on which packages you used; the PGDG installation places `libpq` in `/usr/pgsql-10/lib` with package `postgresql10-libs`. In case of doubt, try `rpm -qa|grep postgres`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by assigning the path to the libpq library an environment variable like this:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/pgsql-10/lib/pkgconfig

This command will help find the correct path to the library  'locate libpq.pc'.

Comment: I don't have pkgconfig in pgsql-11